# ReplaceAll and &quot; doesn't replace

Tags: java, string

Can anyone point me out how the first if works and the second doesn't? I'm puzzled why the second if-clause isn't working. I'd like to get a hint, thanks.

```
String msg = o.getTweet();
        if (msg.indexOf("&amp;") > 0) {
            msg = msg.replaceAll("&amp;", "&");// vervangt &amp; door &
        }
        if (msg.indexOf("&quot;") > 0) {
            msg = msg.replaceAll("&quot;", "aa"); //vervangt &quot; door "
        }
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it ? Which worked and which didn't ?

Comment: if you are parsing HTML file then should use some HTMLParser instead of doing it manually.

Comment: The &amp; worked out fine, it shows an &. When I try a message with quotes, it stays &quot;

Comment: @Harry Joy, I'm parsing a string that contains a tweet message.

Comment: what is the output you see?, can you give the input you gave and output you received and expected

Comment: @Hannelore : Show us the error you'r getting.

Comment: @roadrunner, I'm not getting any error, it just displays &quot;
@Ajay, for example I have a String containing "Test" and it displays &quot;Test&quot;

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because `ZERO` is a **very valid** index. Try this out,

```
    String msg = o.getTweet();
    if (msg.indexOf("&amp;") != -1) {
        msg = msg.replaceAll("&amp;", "&");// vervangt &amp; door &
    }
    if (msg.indexOf("&quot;") != -1) {
        msg = msg.replaceAll("&quot;", "aa"); //vervangt &quot; door "
    }
```

**Explanation:**

The documentation of `String.indexOf(String str)` explains that, *"if the string argument occurs as a substring within this object, then the index of the first character of the first such substring is returned; if it does not occur as a substring, -1 is returned."* - [[link to docs]](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29)

This can be done as simple as below, as [OpenSauce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/583274/opensauce) pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069475/replaceall-and-quot-doesnt-replace/6069660#6069660).

```
msg = msg.replace("&amp;", "&").replace("&quot;", "\"");
```

**Useful links:**

- [String `indexOf()` docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29)
- [String `replace()` docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)
- [String `replaceAll()` docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: This works perfectly! Could you give me a little more explanation why -1 is better than zero? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd even recommend removing the `if` altogether.

Comment: @Hannelore: When your string begins with `"&quot;"`, `indexOf` will return 0 because counting starts at 0.

Comment: @Hannelore As Adeel says, 0 is a valid index - it means the first character of the string. So your code was buggy because it considered 0 to mean "not found" - but it does not mean that in this case.

Comment: Thanks to all of you folks to support the answer. @Hannelore: I am adding the docs excerpt + link.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to check the substring exists, the `replace` and `replaceAll` methods are no-ops if the substring is not found.  Since you're not looking for regexes, you can also use `replace` instead of `replaceAll` - it will be somewhat more efficient, and won't surprise you if you also want to check for other strings which happen to contain regex special chars.

```
msg = msg.replace("&amp;", "&").replace("&quot;", "\"");
```

note that `replace` does indeed replace *all* matches, like you want. The difference between `replace` and `replaceAll` is whether the arg is interpreted as a regex or not.

Comment: That's a confusing API design choice!

Comment: I didn't know that `replace` was replacing all occurences. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: +1 nice answer especially the bit about replace equivalent to replaceAll if using only characters. I guess that is why you have replaceFirst to do it only for the first match.

Comment: @Robin Green: Yes, the naming of `replace` and `replaceAll` is confusing. Not the only place where the Java API uses problematic names...

Comment: +1. A fair point indeed. Like to give another + for pointing out the difference of `replace()` and `replaceAll()`.